# Depend clause in openmp is not respecting dependence declared

Tags: openmp

I am trying to use openmp tasks to schedule a tiled execution of basic jacobi2d computation. In jacobi2d there is a dependence on A(i,j) from

A(i, j)
A(i-1, j)
A(i+1, j)
A(i, j-1)
A(i, j+1).

To my understanding of the depend clause I am declaring the dependences correctly, but they are not being respected while executing the code. I have copied the simplified code piece below. Initially my guess was that the out of bounds ranges for some tiles might be causing this issue, so I corrected that but the issue persists.(I have not copied the longer code with corrected tile ranges as that part is just a bunch of ifs + max)

```
int n=8,tsteps=2,b=4;         //n - size of matrix, tsteps - time iterations, b - tile size or block size

#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp master
for (t=0; t<tsteps; ++t)
  {
    for (i=0; i<n; i+=b)
      for (j=0; j<n; j+=b)
      {
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(t,i,j) depend(in:A[i-1:b+2][j-1:b+2]) depend(out:B[i:b][j:b])
        { 
          #pragma omp critical  
          printf("t-%d i-%d j-%d --A",t,i,j);     //Prints out time loop, i,j 
        }
      } 
    for (i=0; i<n; i+=b)
      for (j=0; j<n; j+=b)
      {
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(t,i,j) depend(in:B[i-1:b+2][j-1:b+2]) depend(out:A[i:b][j:b])
        {
          #pragma omp critical  
          printf("t-%d i-%d j-%d --B",t,i,j);     //Prints out time loop, i,j 
        }
      }
  }
}
}
```

So the idea with declaring dependence starting from i-1 and j-1 and the range being (b+2) is that the neighbouring tiles also affect your current tiles calculations. And similarly for the second set of loop where values in A should only be overwritten once the neighbouring tiles have used the values.

Code is being compiled using gcc 5.3 which supports openmp 4.0.

ps: the way array range is declared above denotes the starting position and the number of indices to be considered while creating the dependence graph.

edit (based on Zulan's comment) - changed the inner code to a simple print statement as this will suffice to check order of task execution. Ideally for the above values(since there are only 4 tiles) all tiles should complete the first printf and then only execute the second. But if you execute the code it will mix the order.

Comment: Why don't you just use work sharing on the loops?  In the first loop you read from `B` but write to `A`. In the second loop you write to `A` and read from `B`. So do part1 first in parallel and then part2 in parallel. Just make sure you sync the threads between part1 and part2 (which should be implicit anyway unless you use `nowait`).

Comment: Surely the conditions are all wrong? ("if ((ii!=0 || ii!=n-1) || (jj!=0 || jj!=n-1))". Consider ii==0, that will still execute since 0!=n-1, but you don't want it to since it generates an out of bounds access...

Comment: @Zboson - Yes that can be done as well, its just that using tasks gives you a slightly more efficient use as ideally smaller tasks give you a higher parallelism and less synchronization is required.


@ Jim. Yes you are right, that is an error with the code. The thing is the dependence issue still exists. I tracked the dependence and execution order using a single print before the 2 inner ii and jj for loops. And the order of print statements is incorrect. I took the precaution of putting this print in a critical pragma as otherwise the print can be wildly incorrect.

Comment: Please edit your code to provide a proper [mcve]. This means 1) Remove irrelevant parts of the code. 2) Fix remaining errors 3) Include your print statements if they are the basis of your current conclusions 4) Make the code compileable. P.S. Minimal does not imply that you need or should skimp on brackets.

Comment: @hajmola, can you please also provide information on which compiler you are using? the `depend` clause was only added in OpenMP 4.0...

Comment: I have isolated the issue  to the depend clause but I am still not sure of the correct method of declaring ranges. I will modify the code to make it easier to discuss(as pointed out by Zulan, apologies!)

@Klaas - I am using gcc 5.3.0 (which supports openmp 4.0) to compile the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out the issue, even though OpenMP specs say that depend clause is supposed to be implemented with a starting point and range, it has not been implemented yet in gcc. So currently it only compares the starting point from the depend clause (depend(in:A[i-1:b+2][j-1:b+2])) A[i-1][j-1] in this case.

Initially I was comparing elements in different relative tile positions. Eg comparing (0,0) element with the last element of the tile, which was giving a no conflicts with dependence and hence the random order of execution of various tasks.

Current gcc implementation does not care about the range provided in the clause at all.